# XAMPP 400 bad request

Tags: apache, http, xampp

When I send request via browser (localhost) then everything is OK, but when I send it from different IP I get error 400. How can it possible?
I've checked my firewall and it's open. Why server doesn't understand the request when it's sent from different IP? :/

I use Apache (XAMPP). #HELP! I really have no idea, what can be wrong.

[good and bad server response with the same request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY7Y8.png)

Comment: Two main differences are easily seen in your screenshot - the first request seems to send a referrer and a user-agent, whereas the second one contains neither. Often times systems are set up to check those values to try and discover requests made by “bots”, and block them.

Comment: Hello @CBroe ! :)
I admit, that I'm the newbiest newbie in it. I send the second request from the microcontroller. What should I put in referrer and user-agent field? How can I modify my request to fit the syntax?